# getting the following error when I run my code, 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, tkinter

I posted the relevant code as well as the full traceback for the error. I have tried converting different elements to int, but none of that has worked.  How can I fix this problem so that my code runs correctly and inserts data from the list into my listbox?

```python
import typing
from typing import Text

import WearablesDataInterpreter
from WearablesDataInterpreter import *

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ALL, ANCHOR, Entry, Listbox

import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk

import tkmacosx
from tkmacosx import Button

from datetime import datetime

import sqlite3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

import numpy as np

import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

import math 
from math import sqrt


def search_box_frame5(frame5):
    def update(data):
        input_list.delete(0, tk.END)

        for item in data:
            data.insert(tk.END, item)

    def fillout(e):
        user_input.delete(0, tk.END)
        user_input.insert(0, input_list.get(ANCHOR))

    def check(e):
        typed = user_input.get()
        if typed == '':
            data = date_store
        else :
            data = []
            for item in date_store:
                if typed.lower() in item.lower():
                    data.append(item)
        update(data)
        
    date_store = [753, 756, 758, 761]
    

    user_input = tk.Entry(frame5, width = 40)
    user_input.pack()
    input_list = Listbox(frame5, width = 40)
    input_list.pack(pady=10)

    update(date_store)

    input_list.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", fillout)
    user_input.bind("<KeyRelease>", check)

ef load_frame5():

    clear_widgets(frame1)
    frame5.tkraise()
    frame5.pack_propagate(False)

    logo_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = '/Users/piacobelli/Desktop/WearalesDataAnalyzer/ME Logo.png')
    logo_widget = tk.Label(frame5, image = logo_img, bg = 'white')
    logo_widget.image = logo_img
    logo_widget.pack(pady=(10,0))

    AccelerometerRegressionPlotMostRecent_widget = Button(frame5, bg = 'white', borderless = 1, text = "Accelerometer Regression Plot (Most Recent)", command = lambda: AccRegressionPlot())
    AccelerometerRegressionPlotMostRecent_widget.pack(pady=(60, 20))
    
    AccelerometerRegressionPlotOther_widget = Button(frame5, bg = 'white', borderless = 1, text = "Accelerometer Regression Plot (Other Timepoint)", command = lambda: search_box_frame5(frame5))
    AccelerometerRegressionPlotOther_widget.pack(pady=20)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('ML Analayzer')
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width = 520, height = 613, bg = bg_color)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, width = 520, height = 613, bg = bg_color)
frame3 = tk.Frame(root, width = 520, height = 613, bg = bg_color)
frame4 = tk.Frame(root, width = 520, height = 613, bg = bg_color)
frame5 = tk.Frame(root, width = 520, height = 613, bg = bg_color)

load_frame1()
root.mainloop()
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidgets/button_base.py", line 893, in cmd
    self.cnf['command']()
  File "/Users/piacobelli/Desktop/WearalesDataAnalyzer/MLDataAnalyzer.py", line 241, in <lambda>
    AccelerometerRegressionPlotOther_widget = Button(frame5, bg = 'white', borderless = 1, text = "Accelerometer Regression Plot (Other Timepoint)", command = lambda: search_box_frame5(frame5))
  File "/Users/piacobelli/Desktop/WearalesDataAnalyzer/MLDataAnalyzer.py", line 73, in search_box_frame5
    update(date_store)
  File "/Users/piacobelli/Desktop/WearalesDataAnalyzer/MLDataAnalyzer.py", line 48, in update
    data.insert(tk.END, item)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146). Please also ensure your code is a complete [mre], including imports and setup code, as well as definitions for all variables used. We should be able to paste a single block of your code into a file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks, I made the edits as you suggested.

Comment: Are you sure that is the full error traceback?  I would expect the error `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` to be preceded by a call to `int()`, but it is not there.

Answer (score 2):

In line 48, you probably meant to write `input_list.insert(tk.END, item)`

`data` is a list, its method `.insert` doesn't work with `tk.END` (which is the string 'end')

`input_list` is instead a `tkinter.Listbox` and its `.insert` does perfectly fine with it